# How to Save image into project folder using jQuery in ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I'm new to ASP.NET and would be grateful if someone could help.
I have my file input in a view:

```
 <input type="file" name="Image" id ="filename" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" id ="sub" />
```

Then in the script i send it's value to my Action in a Controller

```
$(function () {
    $.post("Home/NewProject", {Image: $("#filename").val() }, function (data) {});
});
```

In the Controller's action i get the filename, and rename it as one which will be stored in my project folder `~/App_Data/uploads`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewProject(Project model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         bool ok = false;
         ViewBag.Message = "Publish your project." ;
         //var photo = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
         var fileName = model.Image;

         // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
         var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
         model.Image = path;
    }
}
```

But how can I actually SAVE this file into folder?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want upload file to server with Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upload files using jQuery ajax. If the client browser supports the HTML5 File API you could achieve that with the XHR2 object as shown in [`this article`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications). If not you could use some file upload plugin such as [`Fine Uploader`](http://fineuploader.com/), [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) or the [`jquery.form plugin`](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

Here's an example with the jQuery form plugin:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("someaction", "somecontroller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="Image" id ="filename" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id ="sub" />    
}
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {
        alert('thanks for submitting');
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry for gravedigging on this post by commenting but I'm a complete novice when it comes to jquery, javascript etc... but I need one of my forms to be able to upload an image (scan from doctors note) and then save it to one of the folders in my application, I don't see anywhere the path is being set as to where it is saved to, could you elaborate on that for a bit please?